# Change grid template at break point

Tags: html, css

i have some product pad and i try to change grid template at break point 1200.

It's really necessary that product doesn't have area but auto flow.

Under breakpoint, unless having 2 columns 3 row i have 3 columns with one masked. 
I think something is missing in grid-3-2 and auto-flow doesn't solve the problem. 
i have to follow the li order to display.

thanks by advance for your help ! here is my code =)

```css
.grid-3-2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 390px 390px 390px;
    grid-template-rows: 607px 607px 260px 607px 607px;
    grid-row-gap: 61px;
    grid-column-gap: 2px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 21px;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px){
    .grid-3-2{
        display: grid;
        max-width: 782px;
        grid-template-columns: 390px 390px;
        grid-template-rows: 607px 607px 607px 260px 607px 607px 607px;
        grid-row-gap: 61px;
        grid-column-gap: 2px;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: -40px;
        margin-top: 21px;
    }   
}
```

```html
<ol class="grid-3-2">
    <li class="product"></li>
    <li class="product"></li>
    <li class="product"></li>
    <li class="product"></li>
    <li class="product"></li>
    <li class="product"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Do you want to show only two columns at 1200px and other div's just shifting down to its ?

Comment: Hi, I want to show Three columns over 1200, Two under, instead having 3 columns 2 rows i want to have 2 columns 3 rows. ;)

Comment: Your code seems to get the result properly. what is wrong exactly?

Comment: My content is blowout in both side under 1200px :S and still have 3 columns

Comment: for info .product{
   height: 607px;
   z-index: 1;
}

Comment: @Max Can you provide a fiddle link or codepen or any similar link?? it actually works well in the snippet. you can run the snippet in as a full page and you can see.

Comment: @Max You're saying you want **Three columns over 1200px** and after it you are saying **i want to have 2 columns 3 rows**, what does it mean ? Do not be a zig-zag

Comment: Work great thanks, in my li list i have an image that take 3 column... so i just forgot to turn it on two column under 1200px... because it's saturday may be T.T thanks to all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well as it seems. the only thing I recommend to use is `repeat(multiples, value)` as long as all values are equal instead of writing each grid item values needed.

Also when changing something at a breakpoint only write the required change with no duplication of other properties because they will still be applied.

**The following example is similar to yours but with minimal values, run the snippet using full page and resize the page to notice the difference.**

```css
.product {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.grid-3-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  .grid-3-2 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ol class="grid-3-2">
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
  <li class="product"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found why it's not working, i've an image pad who's take a row. when i remove it it's work.  Because grid-column-start: 1;
                    grid-column-end: 4;

## facepalm .....

Thanks for help, i will do grid-column-start: 1;
                    grid-column-end: 3;